# What do I lose when going into bankruptcy?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I am currently in Colonia and I'm not really up for the return trip, and I was wondering if I could simply declare bankruptcy to go back to the bubble.

Will I lose my materials and engineers data if I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you'll keep your engineer data and materials, you'll only loose any cargo in your hold and any scan data (plus the cost of re-buying a ship, of course).  Although declaring bankruptcy, in my opinion, isn't the best option as a % of your earnings will be taken from you to repay the new ship costs and it will simply drop you in a random sector with a Sidewinder & 1000 credits.

Sources: My own experience and [this thread](https://forums.frontier.co.uk/showthread.php/270500-Loss-of-Engineers-Cargo)

Comment: Will i also lose my 13M credits by doing this ?

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade all of your modules. Sell off all commodities. Sell any exploration data you can. Buy the cheapest ship you can (sidewinder), sell your other ship. Then, commit suicide in the sidewinder. On the rebuy screen, instead of paying 5% to get your ship back, take the free sidewinder in your starter system.

If you do that, you'll retain most of your money (except 10% of your ship's cost and 32,000 credits for the sidewinder). Engineer materials and data will be kept. Engineered modules will be lost.